# How to use ProgramData folder on Windows

Tags: windows

I assume to use ProgramData folder on Windows to save configuration files and log files of my application program.

Regarding configuration files, they're just created during instalation, and not edited after the installation. (The installation is performed by Administrator)
Threfore it is no problem.

On the other hand, log files are written while the program is executing.
But the ProgramData folder's priviledges do not allow to write for Users group by default.

Hence, I think I should change default priviledges.
But I'm not sure it is correct, or not.

Generally, do you add a privilege to write to your application log folder in ProgramData?

Thanks.

Comment: ProgramData is not suitable for this purpose, you don't have write access.  Use AppData instead.  Storing the config files there is okay, as long as those files don't have user-specific config.

Comment: "ProgramData" grants full control to the creator of subfolders and files, and all users have the right to create folders and files in "ProgramData". If your application creates a subdirectory here, the creating user has full control of it, and other users can create files and subdirectories there that they in turn have full control over. But users won't be able to modify other users' files. However, since the original creating user has full control of the directory, you can of course grant all users the right to modify the files in the directory.

Comment: This isn't commonly done. Normally static configuration files would be installed in the program directory, not in "ProgramData", and logs would be stored per-user in "AppData" (local or maybe roaming). If there's a logging or data component that should be shared among all users, that could go in a "ProgramData" subdirectory that has custom security. But actually that might be better managed by a service component that's shared by all users.

Comment: So where should a service application then write its log files to? (I have a .NET Core app and for Linux compatibility I don't want to use the Windows Event Log but a simple file path which can be configured in a static config file)

Comment: I decided my sservice application put the logs into the ProgramData folder. I am not sure that behavior is common, but some log files of application installed my PC were located there.